# I get a error message when I set up a web driver (selenium with php)

Tags: php, selenium, automated-tests

How do I get rid of this error that comes out of me when I run a `example.php` test?

I get 3 error message:

1. > ( ! ) Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$sessionId in
   >   C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDriver\phpwebdriver\WebDriver.php on line 60
2. > ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object
   >   context in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDriver\example.php on line 24
3. > ( ! ) Error: Using $this when not in object context in
   >   C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDriver\example.php on line 24

I am new in testing with selenium, and I really do not know how to solve this. I tried to install various drivers but without success

Error message in the terminal:

> 22:37:50.504 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched
>   factory
>   org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provi
>   der: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService) 22:37:50.929 INFO
>   [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {   "browserName":
>   "chrome",   "javascriptEnabled": true,   "nativeEvents": false,
>   "version": "" }

Comment: I've sorted out all the error except one. I do not know how to get rid of this. Help

( ! ) Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ELEMENT in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDriver\phpwebdriver\WebElement.php on line 28


in terminal 

23:00:10.206 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService)

Comment: My running code:

require_once "phpwebdriver/WebDriver.php";

$webdriver = new WebDriver("localhost", "4444");
$webdriver->connect("firefox");
$webdriver->get("http://google.com");
$element = $webdriver->findElementBy(LocatorStrategy::name, "q");
if ($element) {
    $element->sendKeys(array("php webdriver" ) );
    $element->submit();
}